# SONAR complaining about Make the enclosing method "static" or remove this set

Tags: java, spring, performance, static, sonarqube

I have the following piece of code in my program and I am running SonarQube 5 for code quality check on it after integrating it with Maven.

However, Sonar is asking to Make the enclosing method "static" or remove this set. the method is setApplicationContext.

How to remove this error? Why this error is coming?

```
public class SharedContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
public static final String REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY = "reportEngineFactory";
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    SharedContext.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}

public Object getBean(String name) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(name);
} }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be specific, you appear to be asking about rule S2696, 'Instance methods should not write to "static" fields'

As the rule description details:

> Correctly updating a `static` field from a non-static method is tricky to get right and could easily lead to bugs if there are multiple class instances and/or multiple threads in play. Ideally, `static` fields are only updated from `synchronized static` methods.

Thus, the issue is telling you to make the method on which it was raised (presumably `setApplicationContext`) `static`, so that across all class instances there is only one copy of that method making updates to the `static` (i.e. shared across all class instances) field `applicationContext`. It additionally recommends making the method `synchronized` so that only one instance at a time can call the method.

**Late edit:** To see the rule description click either the "See Rule" or the "..." (depending on your version of SonarQube) shown after the issue message.

Comment: To add some context, any developer who sees that you have a non-static `setApplicationContext` method will think that it will change the application context only for that instance, not for all of the instance of the application.

Comment: you cannot make it static. because you will violate the contract for ApplicationContextAware

Comment: Where do you find this rule description?

Comment: See my expansion @Nick.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. The OP is indicating a situation that is currently an accepted practice within the Spring Framework world when it is necessary to grab the Application Context (such as in the case of a custom shutdown manager). Making the method static breaks the contract. Maybe the problem is with Spring, but this does not resolve the issue beyond offering an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: @ccellist, OP asks "How to remove this error? Why this error is coming?" I think I've answered both fairly thoroughly.

Comment: Does not answer the question, as making this method static would break the contract of the overriden function.

Answer (score 12):

For what it's worth, and I'm probably going to get blacklisted by the Sonar community specifically and the Java Universe in general for saying this, adding `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2696")` to the top of the offending method causes Sonar to ignore that warning completely.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
@Setter
private static volatile ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    setContext(ac);
}
```

Comment: Non-primitive fields should not be "volatile"

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today. @G.Ann explained why this sonar issue happens and how it can be removed. The way G.Ann suggested will not be worked in this particular scenario.

When someone wants to override a method, the method signature can not be changed hence we can't add static or synchronised in the method signature.

```
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    //implmentation
}
```

So we can try @ccelis way to suppress the sonar warnings. but I don't like to do that.

@user16101992 said we can use volatile in the applicationContext declaration but this is not a good approach since it will [violate the Non-primitive fields should not be "volatile" sonar violation](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/x/UzdGBQ).

Hence we can't change the method signature, we can remove the static from the applicationContext variable declaration.

```
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

With this one, we can remove the violation and we don't need to worry about the object creation for the applicationContext since the spring framework follows the singleton factory pattern to create the applicationContext.