# Sonar: Instance methods should not write to "static" fields

Tags: java, spring, static, sonarqube

I am getting this prompt from Sonar: **Instance methods should not write to "static" fields**

I'm not quite sure what I need to change to fix this issue.

Does "SemaMonitorProxy.applicationContext" have to equal a static method?

```
public class SemaMonitorProxy implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    public void registerFailedLoginAttempt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        final SemaMonitor semaMonitor = applicationContext.getBean(SemaMonitor.class);
        semaMonitor.registerFailedLoginAttempt(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SemaMonitorProxy.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not a Sonar specialist, but what I can imagine is that it might be dangerous to write to a static field in parallel. Just try add a synchronize block on SemaMonitorProxy.class and see if the warning goes away.

Comment: The problem is you are setting the value of static field through a non-static field. Can you make the `setApplicationContext` method as `synchrozied`? I believe that should be enough to fix this.

Comment: There is a proper solution in
[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136302/findbugs-error-write-to-static-field-from-instance-method/21136731).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this method:

```
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    SemaMonitorProxy.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
```

is an instance method writing to a static field:

```
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext
```

You cannot make the above method static. So the only solution would be to remove the static keyword from the `applicationContext` declaration.

```
private ApplicationContext applicationContext
```

Comment: I can't set setApplicationContext to static because then it wont be able to override ApplicationContextAware, which isn't an interface I can't change since it's part of the spring framework.

Comment: @KevinM: absolutely right. I suggest to make the applicationContext non static. It is typically a singleton anyway which exists once in memory. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rule `java:S2696`

> Correctly updating a `static` field from a non-static method is tricky to get right and could easily lead to bugs if there are multiple class instances and/or multiple threads in play. Ideally, `static` fields are only updated from `synchronized static` methods.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407962/974442) answer from @G. Ann - SonarSource Team